# Linq query with dynamic columns selected from a table

Tags: linq

I have two tables. The first contains (amongst others) 20 columns named "CustomCode1" to "CustomCode20". These contain values for data that can be associated with the relevant custom codes. The other table contains 20 rows. Each row (with ID 1 to 20) is associated with the relevant column in the first table. The second table has a column for "Enabled".

What I need is to only select the enabled columns from the first tables.

e.g. suppose ID 10, 15 and 20 are enabled in the second table, I only want to select the value in the columns CustomCode10, CustomCode15 and CustomCode20.

I know this isn't the best design for the tables, but I am having to work with what I have been given. There will only ever be these 20 codes.

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Edit:

I have this in SQL which will only return values for the fields which are enabled:

select 
    case when ((select enabled from customcodes where id = 1) = 1) then CustomCode1 end as CustomCode1, 
    case when ((select enabled from customcodes where id = 2) = 1) then CustomCode2 end as CustomCode2, 
    case when ((select enabled from customcodes where id = 3) = 1) then CustomCode3 end as CustomCode3,
    case when ((select enabled from customcodes where id = 4) = 1) then CustomCode4 end as CustomCode4,
    case when ((select enabled from customcodes where id = 5) = 1) then CustomCode5 end as CustomCode5, 
    case when ((select enabled from customcodes where id = 6) = 1) then CustomCode6 end as CustomCode6,
    case when ((select enabled from customcodes where id = 7) = 1) then CustomCode7 end as CustomCode7, 
    case when ((select enabled from customcodes where id = 8) = 1) then CustomCode8 end as CustomCode8, 
    case when ((select enabled from customcodes where id = 9) = 1) then CustomCode9 end as CustomCode9,
    case when ((select enabled from customcodes where id = 10) = 1) then CustomCode10 end as CustomCode10, 
    case when ((select enabled from customcodes where id = 11) = 1) then CustomCode11 end as CustomCode11,
    case when ((select enabled from customcodes where id = 12) = 1) then CustomCode12 end as CustomCode12,
    case when ((select enabled from customcodes where id = 13) = 1) then CustomCode13 end as CustomCode13,
    case when ((select enabled from customcodes where id = 14) = 1) then CustomCode14 end as CustomCode14,
    case when ((select enabled from customcodes where id = 15) = 1) then CustomCode15 end as CustomCode15,
    case when ((select enabled from customcodes where id = 16) = 1) then CustomCode16 end as CustomCode16,
    case when ((select enabled from customcodes where id = 17) = 1) then CustomCode17 end as CustomCode17, 
    case when ((select enabled from customcodes where id = 18) = 1) then CustomCode18 end as CustomCode18, 
    case when ((select enabled from customcodes where id = 19) = 1) then CustomCode19 end as CustomCode19, 
    case when ((select enabled from customcodes where id = 20) = 1) then CustomCode20 end as CustomCode20
from Customers
where customeraccountnumber = 'XXX'

But need a Linq equivalent. I can remove the null values returned elsewhere.

Comment: Please add some code examples that you've tried already.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a join like this :

```
        using (yourDbContext dc = new yourDbContext())
        {
            var result = (from ro in dc.YourFirstTable
                          join pr in dc.YourSecondTable
                          on ro.RelatedID equals pr.RelatedID 
                          where ro.Enabled == true && 
                          pr.AnyColumnYouWant == "SomeValue"
                          select  new
                          {
                 FirstProperty = ro.User_FullName, //you give a name to your property, 
                 SecondProperty = pr.Proj_Date
                 ...
                 ...

                          }).ToList();
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately there is no ID relating the records in the two tables. I only need the columns from the first table selected where the ID of the row in the second table matches the Column Names from the first

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand what you mean exactly. You can match columns to make a join. But, you should specify which columns you want to match.

Comment: That's the problem I have. The second table specifies which columns to select. There is no correlation between the actual data in the tables.